# r ls list.files pattern curly bracket expansion globbing does not work

Tags: r, regex, glob

I need curly bracket expansion in the `pattern` argument of the R functions `base::ls` and `base::list.files`. For example:

```sh
# in terminal
ls
# string1  stringX  stringYZ
ls string{1,X}
# string1  stringX
```

but

```r
# in R
list.files()
# "string1"  "stringX"  "stringYZ"
list.files(pattern="string{1,X}")
# error: invalid 'pattern' regular expression
list.files(pattern="string\\{1,X\\}")
# character(0) # i.e. finds nothing
list.files(pattern=glob2rx("string{1,X}"))
# character(0) # i.e. finds nothing
```

Same is true for `base::ls`.

Thanks a lot for help,
Chris

Comment: Try: "string1$|X$" or "string(1|X)$"

Comment: Try: `list.files(pattern="^string(1|X)$")`

Comment: In Bash, `{1,X}` means either `1` or `X`. Thus, you need either `string(1|X)` or (here, since the `1` and `X` are single chars) `string(?:1|X)` or `string[1X]`

Answer (score 0):

`list.files(pattern="^string(1|X)$")` works (`list.files(pattern="string(1|X)")` as well).
Thanks!

Comment: The difference is, that `string(1|X)` will match also e.g. `Astring1` what `ls string{1,X}` and also `^string(1|X)$` will not.

Answer (score 0):

A result like `ls string{1,X}` in *sh* you can get with:

```
list.files(pattern="^string(1|X)$")
```

Alternatively, as pointed out already by @wiktor-stribiżew in the comments, you can use:

```
list.files(pattern="^string[1X]$")
```

To have a *full string match* you have to surround the pattern with `^` and `$`. Thanks to @wiktor-stribiżew for this comment.

Comment: You can mention that globs require a full string match, that is why you use `^` and `$` anchors.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider using the `glob()` function from the [{bracer}](https://github.com/trevorld/bracer) package:

```r
bracer::glob("string{1,X}")
```

```
[1] "string1" "stringX"
```